# Screenshot go 'nowhere' after Dropbox installation

Tags: macos, screen-capture, dropbox

I installed dropbox and now my screenshots go to dropbox, I tried disabling "Share screenshots using dropbox" but now screenshots don't go to the folder but also not to the clipboard

How can I store screenshots again?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. You can always ask additional questions in, well, new questions.

Comment: Are you using the built-in Screenshot options Mac OS provides?

Answer (score 1):

To check where screenshots are currently assigned, in Terminal type

```
defaults read com.apple.screencapture location
```

By default that would actually return no answer, as the line should only be written if you ever change it - so I'm assuming Dropbox did change it at some point.

To reset it to the default desktop location, type

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop
```

followed by

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

This should cover for  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>  &  <kbd>4</kbd>  screenshots. Screenshots to clipboard should be unaffected, & still be activated by adding  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  to either of the above methods.

Comment: Hi, the first command outputted - 
"2017-04-07 10:04:42.880 defaults[1193:108936] 
The domain/default pair of (com.apple.screencapture, location) does not exist".

In the past Cmd ⌘  Shift ⇧  4 also sent the screenshot to the clipboard for all i recall, i didnt have to use Ctrl ^..

Comment: OK, so it didn't have a default set - which ought to mean it should go to desktop. Try setting the location again to make sure. Snap to disk & snap to clipboard have never been the same key command, btw.